Build only dependency not working if deps.json file present
We are creating a series of C# / .NET 8.0 applications that all make use of an API provided by another application (let's call it BaseApp).
Initially, we were adding a reference to the assembly that implements said API directly (BaseApp.API.dll), pointing at its installation folder. However, we need to build our applications through Azure Devops pipelines and it's not feasible to install the application there, manage the updates, etc.
So I thought I would generate a nuget package with just the assembly we need to reference and use it only as a build dependency. This way, we can manage versioning and stuff, and it's easy to create applications that use this API.
From this link I learnt that by setting PrivateAssets to All I can do just that.
And it is mostly working, except I need to delete the deps.json file from the output folder. That is, if the deps.json file exists in the folder where I'm running the app (BaseApp's installation folder), I get an error that it cannot find the assembly.

If I remove it or rename the deps.json file, it works correctly. Also, the deps.json file does not reference, in any way, the BaseApp.API.dll.
Any idea what I'm missing or how can I solve it?
